# How to use IObservable<T> as a source for a WPF source binding to a ListBox?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, system.reactive

So this is what I am *currently* doing:

I have a WPF ListBox that is currently data bounded to and populated by a

```
public ObservableCollection<string> SourceBinding
{
  get;
  set;
}
```

This WPF bounded source has an OnCollectionChanged event handler that does the following whenever a new item is added;

```
ObservableCollection<string> source = new ObservableCollection<String>();

private void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    NotifyPropertyChanged("NotifyPropertyChanged")
}
```

I am also subscribed to an `IObservable<string>` stream that is handling each tick via the `TickHHandler` event handler;

```
Stream.Subscribe(TickHandler);
```

TickHandler is currently doigng this:

```
    private void TestSubscription( string item)
    {
        sourceBinding.Add(item)            
    }
```

Here, for each output tick event from the Rx stream, the ObservableCollection is updated and the WPF GUI is notified of the changes that need to be made.

What I would ***like*** to do however,  is bind the ListBox directly to my `IObservable<string>` stream preferably inside xaml.

I am assuming that I'd somehow have to use Behaviors to expose a custom `IObservableItemsSource` property to bind the `IObservable<string>` source for consumption. I imagine it would look something like this in the end:

```
IObservableItemsSource ="{Binding IObservableSource}"
```

I know how to implement Behavior, but I have no idea how to start creating an `IObservable<string>` property for use in xaml, or if this is even possible!

Am I way off the mark? Can someone explain what the best way to implement this should be?

Thanks.

Comment: Bindings don't know jack about observables.  Your assumption is incorrect--you'd want to provide an implementation of [BindingBase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase(v=vs.110).aspx) that does know what an observable is.  There's a ReactiveUI framework out there that might provide one for you, but i'm not sure.  I'd wager it's called *ObservableBinding* or something similar.

Answer (score -1):

The Observable Collection implement INotifyCollectionChanged which will alert the xaml that it needs to update the view. So if you just add to the collection as you are doing it should update the UI automatically as long as you are binding it correctly to the ViewModel.

This is the view

```
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Content="{Binding}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

This is the code behind

```
    public class ViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<string> Collection { get; set; }

    }
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var vm = new ViewModel();
            vm.Collection = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            this.DataContext = vm;
            vm.Collection.Add("Item");
            vm.Collection.Add("Item");
            vm.Collection.Add("Item");
            vm.Collection.Add("Item");
            vm.Collection.Add("Item");


        }
```

Note that as long as you are doing your processing in the UI thread you this will work. If you are doing it in a background thread you will need to dispatch and add to the observable collection in the UI thread.

Comment: Yes. I am already doing this. I want to bind to an IObservable<T> Reactive Extensions stream, however.

Comment: The best way to do it, is derive a sub class from one of the objects then implement an the interface for the for the other class. That way it would encapsulate it. If i am understanding you correctly.